# Detect write to DebugFS

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a kernel module that creates several DebugFS entries, each 4 to 8 bytes. I would like to use one (or more) of these entries to initiate action within the kernel module--in other words, I want to use an entry for configuration purposes.
Is there a common idiom to detect the user write to the DebugFS entry without polling (some kind of user-space to kernel space signal) within my kernel module, or is sleep/poll the best (only?) option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helper functions like `debugfs_create_u32()` are intended for cases where you want to be able to change a variable without any other helper code.

If you want to do anything but setting a variable, you have to implement your own file operations with `debugfs_create_file()`.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I wasn't sure of the difference between the 2--specifically, I thought maybe debugfs_create_file() was specialized for accessing large amounts of data. It sounds like I would need to copy how (for example) debug_fs_create_u32() is implemented, but then modify the read/write fops. I'll try this. Thanks for the help!